# How to specify array to Dygraph from Razor variable

Tags: c#, razor, dygraphs

I have a string[] of appropriate formatted strings in Session["PnlDataForChart"]

But I cannot display them in Dygraph. I tried to inspect dataArray, but cannot see it in VS debugger, and am not sure how to do it in Firebug.

Is this correctly set for Dygraph?

> From page source:

```
        var dataArray = [];
                <div>
        dataArray.push("Date,Pnl");
        </div>
                <div>
        dataArray.push("2016/11/01 01:01,0.0000");
        </div>
                <div>
        dataArray.push("2016/11/01 01:02,0.0000");
        </div>
                <div>
        dataArray.push("2016/11/01 01:03,0.0000");
        </div>
                <div>
        dataArray.push("2016/11/01 01:04,0.0000");
        </div>
                <div>
        dataArray.push("2016/11/01 01:05,0.0000");
        </div>
                <div>
        dataArray.push("2016/11/01 01:06,0.0000");
        </div>
```

> From View page:

```
<div id="ExportDiv">

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>

    <div id="graphdiv"></div>

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dataArray = [];
        @{
            foreach (var line in (string[])Session["PnlDataForChart"])
            {
                <div>
                dataArray.push("@line");
                </div>
            }
        }

        g = new Dygraph(
          document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
          dataArray
        );
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of mess in your code. Just some of mistakes:

1. After `<div id="graphdiv"></div>` you have `</script>` which is unnecessary.
2. In foreach loop because you're in `<script></script>` block you cannot put `<div></div>`. In script block you can use only JavaScript syntax!
3. To access js variable from foreach loop you must use @: syntax, so you should do this in this way: 
   `@:dataArray.push("@line");`

This is how whole solution should looks like:

Controller:

```
var dataArray = new string[] {
    "Date,Temperature",
    "2008-05-07,75",
    "2008-05-08,70",
    "2008-05-09,80"
};

Session["PnlDataForChart"] = dataArray;
```

And view:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/dygraph.js"></script>

<div id="ExportDiv">
    <div id="graphdiv"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataArray = [];

    @{
        foreach (var line in (string[])Session["PnlDataForChart"])
        {
            @:dataArray.push("@line");
        }
    }

    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv"), dataArray.join('\n'));
</script>
```